# Callback function on state change

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am trying to give a button the on-click property of changing the `sendSubTotals`state to true.If this state is true , I want the children to return the callback function `getSubTotal` to substract the subtotal from each child and then set the `total`. I am having a problem when returning the callback in the child. By using console.log I can see the if the statement (which is based on the parent's state) is being entered , but the callback function from `return ()=>getSubTotal(subTotal)`  still keeps the total at 0.How could I solve this? Thank you very much !

This is the state, which set to True- must send the subtotal of the child to the parent(passed in an onClick event):

```
const [sendSubTotals,setSendSubTotals]=React.useState(false)
const handleTotalClick=(event)=>{
        setSendSubTotals(true)
        event.preventDefault()
    }
```

This is the function that computes the total in the parent:

```
const getSubTotal=(subTotal)=>{
    const result=total+subTotal
     setTotal(result)
     console.log("TOTAL WAS COMPUTED")      
    }
```

This is how I pass props to the children:

```
<ControlledOpenSelect ourObject={ourObject} key={item.id} onRemove={()=>handleRemove(item.id)} getSubTotal={getSubTotal} substractSubTotal={substractSubTotal} sendSubTotals={sendSubTotals} />
```

And this is how I'm calling the `getSubTotal` function in the child:

```
if (sendSubTotals===true){
        console.log("SUBTOTAL OF THIS COMPONENT WAS SENT TO PARENT")
        console.log(subTotal)  
        return ()=>getSubTotal(subTotal)
    }if (sendSubTotals===false){
        console.log("NOT SENT TO PARENT")
    }
```

Comment: can you share your code anywhere code sandbox??

Comment: `getSubTotal={(subTotal) => getSubTotal(subTotal)}` you have to pass the argument

Comment: Here is the code sandbox: https://codesandbox.io/live/cmmecq0.

Comment: @Rajdeep Debnath It doesnt work... This console.log `console.log("TOTAL WAS COMPUTED")`  is never called

Comment: @hector there can be 2 reason, 1. `setTotal(true)` not working  2. the children component code is required as it may not calling `props.getSubTotal` properly

Comment: @Rajdeep Debnath `setSendSubTotals(true)` seems to work as the console is logging in both scenarios (true & false). As for the way I pass the `getSubTotal` props to the child, it is `getSubTotal={getSubTotal}` and then I use destructuring in the child, like `ControlledOpenSelect({getSubTotal, props})`, so I really don't know what I should change...

Comment: Please try this, `ControlledOpenSelect({getSubTotal, ...props})`

Comment: @Rajdeep Debnath Thank you !